# Unable to understand proof for Infinitude of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I have got a proof for showing the infinitude of prime numbers. I am facing issue where the book states that: "Thus, $p_i$ must divide $1$, so then $p_i=1,$"
I feel there is no reason given to understand why $(s-t)$ cannot divide $1$.
 I state that for equality of the product of $(s-t)p_i$ to $1$, both $s-t=1$, & $p_i=1$, as all $s, t, p_i$ are naturals. The book has shown failure for $p_i$, with no proof given for failure of $(s-t) \ne 1$. 
 If $s-t=1$, then $s = p_1p_2\cdots p_{i-1}p_{i+1} \cdots  p_n +1$. 
So, my analysis stops at: it reduces to stating that $s \ne p_1p_2\cdots p_{i-1}p_{i+1} \cdots  p_n +1$.
[image]

Comment: Any book that pretends to give a rigorous proof but uses "..." in a way that is not fully made rigorous elsewhere, is not a good book. Who says we can just multiply all the prime numbers? What if there are infinitely many prime numbers but all are less than some natural number? What if the product of a large number of prime numbers is not divisible by any of them? What if .......

Comment: @user21820 But, if the constraint of finite number of be assumed, then can we not take it to be a valid proof.

Comment: No. I already gave three objections. Are you able to dispel any of them rigorously?

Comment: So, you mean that for rigorous proofs, such extreme considerations are a necessity. I felt that can take finiteness constraints, to be eligible still for being a rigorous proof.

Comment: The fact that you cannot answer to my objections shows that they are indeed valid objections. If you could, you wouldn't be trying to make an excuse for yourself... I'm serious that if you ever want to understand mathematics properly you need to be able to answer my questions.

Comment: Please then show me any proof that rigorousness means that infinite number of primes need be considered. I feel that as in analysis, the rigor has to be diluted for practical cases, else why even Euclid's proof for infinitude of primes need be valid. Please tell me why that is rigorous, and this proof is not. Else, if Euclid's proof is not rigorous, then why it is considered valid.

Comment: Rigorous proofs are not about feelings. And what people did thousands of years ago is not an excuse for what you do today. I've enough of this. If you're really interested in rigorous logic, come and find me in the Logic chat-room. If not, there's nothing else to talk here.

Comment: Please give me address of the chat room.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44058/logic

Comment: @user21820 Is there an infinite subset of the naturals that is bounded above? I don't see how that would be possible? Even if you generalized to the integers you'd run into the same problem given one is prime iff its inverse is prime.

Comment: @DavidReed: It is clear from our discussion that the asker does **not** understand induction, and hence also does not know how to actually prove that there is no infinite bounded subset of the naturals without hand-waving. That is precisely why mathematics education must be revamped; it's not helpful to students because they don't know a lot of things and yet don't know what they don't know. You, of course, know the logic side of this already, so I'm just talking about pedagogy to you. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book states $1=(s-t)p_i$.

Therefore $s-t$ can, and *does*, divide $1$. But that is not at all the point.

Comment: But, a proof for showing failure of $s-t \ne 1$, if could be provided; then I hope my understanding of such proofs would also improve.

Comment: Really, in this proof, no one cares about $s$ and $t$, except for the fact that they are integers, which allows to conclude that $p_i$ divides $1$.

Comment: Can I add upon the given proof / question. I want to make the proof (not only this, but also Euclid's) rigorous, by showing that for each multiplication of primes up to a new $p_i$, can have the new product being mapped by a recursive function into the set of naturals, $\mathbb{N}$. I may need an inductive proof, but need a starting point for that. I mean the base case is okay, as $p_1=2$, but how about the countably infinite set of primes with showing the mapping of all into naturals.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want here - the proof of Euclid's lemma relies upon Euclidean division.
If that's not clear I think that you would need to open a new question, the display would be better and you could afford more words to make this clear.

Comment: I meant by Euclid's proof the Euclid's proof for infinitude of primes. Please confirm that you also meant the same, as I don't feel there is much role of Euclidean division, except division by a particular prime $p_i$, and then arguing that the l.h.s. ($\frac{M}{p_i} - p_1p_2 \cdots p_{i-1}p_{i+1}\cdots p_N$) is an integer, while the r.h.s. ($\frac{1}{p_i}$) is not. By $M$, I mean the new number formed by product of $N$ primes +1.

Comment: I mean that Euclidean division will not make it rigorous, and need a mapping the new number ($M$) to the set of naturals. The gap between a new prime (if new $M$, is a prime) and the earlier one is arbitrary one. If you feel that Euclidean division makes the proof of Euclid rigorous, then please show me.

Comment: Sorry regarding Euclid I had misunderstood. Here is a quite clear translation of Euclid's original proof : https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIX/propIX20.html

Comment: Yes, so I am correct about stating that the Euclid's proof is not rigorous one, as the mapping of $M$ need be shown from the set of $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, with the difficult part being the arbitrariness with which the primes are generated.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(s-t)p_i=1$, since $s-t\in\mathbb Z$ and since $p_i\in\mathbb N$, $s-t=p_i=1$.

Comment: I feel that $s,t$ are also naturals, rather than just integers, please correct me  if wrong.

Comment: @jiten No, you are not wrong. But what I wrote is that $s-t\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference. I request a more elaborate proof on the lines of my attempted proof, for showing that $s-t\ne 1$. I feel that this proof, if given, would enhance my understanding of proofs.